# Fill cells with value = 0 with Red color

Tags: r, gt

I have a table:

[image: table]

and i need to fill cells with `value = 0` with red color.

I realize i need data_color but how to set palette with 2 colors? red if `value==0` , white if `value<>0` ?

I've found an example:

```
    data_color(
  columns = colnames(updates.computers)[2:ncol(updates.computers)],
  colors = scales::col_numeric(
    palette = paletteer::paletteer_d(
               palette = "ggsci::red_material", direction = -1
             ) %>% as.character(),
             domain = NULL
           ),
           alpha = 0.8)
```

But it's not what I need.

[image: example]

I just need cells with 0 to be Red, and all the rest to stay White.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have a look how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `scales::col_bin` function.
By cutting the data into two bins (0 and from 1 to infinity) you can specify the colors for each bin.

```
df <- data.frame(A2020 = sample(0:10, 12, replace = TRUE),
                 B2020 = sample(0:10, 12, replace = TRUE),
                 C2020 = sample(0:10, 12, replace = TRUE),
                 D2020 = sample(0:10, 12, replace = TRUE),
                 E2020 = sample(0:10, 12, replace = TRUE),
                 F2020 = sample(0:10, 12, replace = TRUE),
                 G2020 = sample(0:10, 12, replace = TRUE),
                 H2020 = sample(0:10, 12, replace = TRUE),
                 I2020 = sample(0:10, 12, replace = TRUE),
                 J2020 = sample(0:10, 12, replace = TRUE))

gt(df) %>%
  data_color(
    columns = everything(),
    colors = scales::col_bin(
      bins = c(0, 1, Inf),
      palette = c("red", "white"),
    )
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works. The code:

```
    data_color(
    columns = colnames(updates.computers)[2:ncol(updates.computers)],
    colors = scales::col_bin(
      bins = c(0, 1, Inf),
      palette = c("red", "darkseagreen1"),
    ),
         alpha = 0.8
  )
```

The result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlF3g.png)